# Orders are being canceled automatically in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, order-status

For whatever reason some of my orders (not all of them) are being canceled automatically. I guess there is some job running that does that, but I do not know where to start looking.

Any ideas where to start or what the problem might be?

M2 version is 2.1.9, but it happened in 2.1.6 as well.

Thanks!

Comment: I have same issue with 2.1.5

Comment: did you find the cause of this behavior?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Was there ever a solution to this?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, and tracked it down to orders that were Pending Payment and they would get cancelled over night. The default setting below is set to 8 hours (I know I wrote 4 hours in the image on accident). I increased mine to a year and implemented a process to make sure orders don't get that old. We use the "Pending Payment" to mark orders that are shipped but not paid yet, and the clients are usually given 30-60 days to pay.

[image]

Comment: I was just having the occasional cancellation and it turns out it was that!

Answer (score 0):

```
It seems there is any cron job is running and this cron job hitting any observer function which is changing the status of some of your particulars Orders.

Hence you need to check observer functions manually or you can make search crontab.xml in your project directory this will give all cron jobs xml files and here you can check all instance where code is actually excuted.
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your default order status, suppose for COD method.. you can change your new order status... [image]

Comment: Well, like I said, its does not happen right away after the order has been placed, it happens some hours later. This question is not about the new order state.

Comment: Well , then please set cron job to run every mint...